# Spring DI? Interface Type?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I understand the how, but can't seem formally shape the definitions.

As known DI can be done via constructor or setter or interface. 
I am confused about the latest one -interface based DI, is it used in Spring?

**UPDATE: I gave bad examle in here, which led to wrong understanding.**

**To fix it up:**

***Say we have setter and in setter we inject interface implemented by some class. Is that considered DI via setter or interface?***

http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator
**this article divides DI on:**

"There are three main styles of dependency injection. The names I'm using for them are Constructor Injection, Setter Injection, and Interface Injection. If you read about this stuff in the current discussions about Inversion of Control you'll hear these referred to as type 1 IoC (interface injection), type 2 IoC (setter injection) and type 3 IoC (constructor injection). I find numeric names rather hard to remember, which is why I've used the names I have here."

Else Service Locator pattern used for IoC, is it the one that actually makes possible @Autowired? - ie that not all classes explicitly need to be declared in xml for DI, as we can declare them as @Repository or @Controller or alike again if I recall correctly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Autowiring an interface means wire a bean implementing that interface. This relies on an implementation actually existing in the bean factory.

```
@Autowired
UserService us; // wire a bean implementing UserService
```

--

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    // the @Service annotation causes this implementation of UserService to 
    // be made available for wiring in the bean factory.
}
```

Worth noting is that if you wire by interface, Spring will expect there to exist one and exactly one bean in the bean factory implementing that interface. If more than one bean is found, an error will be thrown and you will have to specify which bean to wire (using the `@Qualifier` annotation).

EDIT:

When wiring, you can either wire a member variable or a setter method.

```
@Autowired
UserService us;
```

--

```
@Autowired
public void setUserService(UserService us) {
    this.us = us;
}
```

These two produce the same result. The difference is that in the former, Spring will use reflection to set the variable `us` to a bean implementing UserService. In the latter, Spring will invoke the `setUserService` method, passing the same UserService imlementation.

Comment: please compare to other DI methods as now I am confused even more. I get the meaning, but lets leave @Autowired for a moment.(forget about context:component-scan - say we don't have it) Show me please the difference between the DI via setter and interface - you can set interface in setter - then what that would be called via interface or via setter? Then why is it formally divided on DI via Setter OR Interface.

Comment: "difference between the DI via setter and interface" - apples and oranges, they have nothing to do with each other. See edit above.

Comment: I understand exactly what you are doing and how it works.(I did implementation myself and it works brilliant) And that is what I thought that it can't be compared. But why does the author of the article place interface injection along the line with setter and constructor injections?

Comment: @Aubergine - the author is describing three different IoC paradigms (at least, his 5 year old version of IoC): constructor, setter and interface. I think he explains fairly well his ideas in the article. Not sure I really understand your question (if, indeed, there is one). FYI, Service Locator is very "EJB 2.0".